# Is there a difference between 'Gegenstand', 'Sache', 'Ding', and 'Dinge'?

Tags: difference, meaning, synonym

Is there a difference between 'Gegenstand', 'Sache', 'Ding', and 'Dinge'? Can we use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, "Dinge" is simply the plural of "Ding".

Then, while all of them have a meaning referring to an object, there are very few instances where you can use all 3 terms interchangeable in the same sentence (I cannot even come up with one) and there are many uses for each of them where none or only one of the others would work, too.

**Examples:**

In these 3 sentences, you could not translate the used term with either of the other 2 terms and keep the same meaning of the sentence:

> - The subject matter of the discussion was a new movie: *Der Gegenstand der Diskussion war ein neuer Film.*
> - This is a complex issue: *Das ist eine komplizierte Sache*
> - This thing here is really complicated: *Das Ding hier ist echt kompliziert!*

Some more explanation for the 3:

- **Ding** - Rather used in casual speech, addressing a tangible object
- **Sache** - Referring to a thing, an affair, an issue
- **Gegenstand** - The most technical term. Referring to an object, subject

Comment: Zuerst Pardon, dass ich die Frage korrigiert habe, so dass dort jetzt "Ding" in Einzahl steht, aber es ist erkennbar, dass Fragen zu Singular und Plural hier nicht explizit gestellt wurden - also sollte man auch nicht drauf eingehen. Stillschweigend solche Fehler zu ignorieren ist aber auch nicht die Sache für ein Forum mit vielen Besuchern, die selbst unsicher sind. Daher gilt es die Frage zu korrigieren, wenn man erreichen kann, dass das, was der Frager fragen wollte, deutlicher wird.

Comment: Dann zum Inhalt Deiner Antwort. "Das ist ein komplizierter Gegenstand" kann man m.E. durchaus sagen. Auch "Das ist ein kompliziertes Ding" aber letzteres nur, wenn es sich um ein materielles Ding handelt - eine Lohnverhandlung etwa ist eher kein Ding. "Das Ding hier ist kompliziert" kann aber auch ein Gegenstand und eine Sache sein. Interessanterweise sagt man `gegenständliche Kunst` für materielles, aber meint abseits davon gerade mit `Gegenstand` oft etwas abstraktes. :)

Comment: The missing *thing* is *"Dinge"* which is used different to mere plural of *"Ding"*, and its not only used colloquial. I disagree with removing this fine but important point from the question.

Comment: @userunknown When you want to say "This is a complex issue", you cannot replace "Sache" with "Ding". If you go in the other direction, you can of course change things. You could also say "Die Sache is kompliziert". I will explain better above.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich stehe wohl auf dem Schlauch. Wo steht `Dinge` nicht für des Dings Plural? Ein anderer Punkt: Im Duden stoße ich auf `Ding` für `Mädchen´ (das kesse Ding!) - das ist i.d. Tat eine Bedeutung, die von den anderen zwei Begriffen nicht übernommen werden kann.

Comment: Strangely the best answer at https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110328022709AAGCQqO is that there's (almost) no difference between `Sache` und `Ding`.