# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Dinge und Sache?

Tags: difference

Beide „Dinge“ und „Sache“ bedeutet circa „Thing“ in englisch oder „cosa“ in Spanisch.
But was ist der Unterschied zwischen Dinge und Sache?

Answer (score 0):

[Words meaning 'thing' - Zeug, Gegenstand, Objekt, Sache, Ding](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/words-meaning-thing-zeug-gegenstand-objekt-sache-ding)

[Is there a difference between 'Gegenstand', 'Sache', 'Ding', and 'Dinge'?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/is-there-a-difference-between-gegenstand-sache-ding-and-dinge)

*Examples:*

*In these 3 sentences, you could not translate the used term with either of the other 2 terms and keep the same meaning of the sentence:*

*The subject matter of the discussion was a new movie: Der Gegenstand der Diskussion war ein neuer Film.*

*This is a complex issue: Das ist eine komplizierte Sache*

*This thing here is really complicated: Das Ding hier ist echt kompliziert!*

*Some more explanation for the 3:*

*Ding - Rather used in casual speech, addressing a tangible object*

*Sache - Referring to a thing, an affair, an issue*

*Gegenstand - The most technical term. Referring to an object, subject*